# How to detect whether a browser enables javascript s.t. the master page can make a proper response?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a site using Asp.net MVC 3 with Razor.

In the `_Layout.cshtml` (the master page) I want to put a logic based on whether or not the browser enables javascript.

What is the simplest way to make this logic?

For the sake of simplicity, let the master  page just output as follows:

```
@if(....)//need to modify
{ <p>javascript enabled...</p>}
else {<p>javascript disabled...</p>}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to find this out on the server, therefore there's no way to find out before the first page is loaded. The best you can do is to put a bit of Javascript into the page that sets a cookie or posts an AJAX response to the server telling it that Javascript is active, so you can do something about it on subsequent page requests. Even apart from the obvious problem of the first page load, it's a bad strategy since the user may switch off Javascript in the meantime while your server still thinks it's active.

[Graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation)/[progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) are the keywords here. Make your page assume by default that no Javascript is active and act accordingly, i.e. serve plain HTML in either case. Include Javascript that will "upgrade" the site's functionality if Javascript is active. Let the client figure out if Javascript is working or not and give it the means to work in either case.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to block the access of your application you can use something like this

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../Controller/Error" />
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no good solution. Almost all of the solutions out there somehow involve running a script to do the check and it doesn't feel right (at least to me). The best solution I can suggest is use the `<noscript />` tag and redirect to a different page that does not depend on javascript.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one trick...

Assume the user has JavaScript blocked (off). We put this code into the index.aspx:

```
<script>
document.location.href = "index.aspx?js=1";
</script>
```

If you get the js=1, you know that user has JS enabled.

So you can generate the code in according the user has / hasn't JS.

The other way is to generate contents witho some special class, e.g. `<div class="noscript">`, and then you run the script (jQuery):

```
$(".noscript").hide();
```

Comment: this one doesn't seems to be a proper solution.

Comment: The problems with this are that a user could switch off Javascript and spoof it with their URL, and on a big page the JQuery script won't fire until the page has loaded (resulting in something vanishing before the user's eyes).